# Input type file is not clearing up when successfully submitting the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

When i am submitting  the form the input text is clearing up but the uploaded file is not clearing. I have used  $scope.addAnswerForm.$setPristine(); but this is not working.

```js
    app.directive('fileModel', ['$parse',
      function($parse) {
        return {
          restrict: 'A',
          link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
            var modelSetter = model.assign;

            element.bind('change', function() {
              scope.$apply(function() {
                modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
              });
            });
          }
        };
      }
    ]);
    app.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
      $scope._answer = {
        text: '',
        comment_pic: ''
      };

      $scope.__answer = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify($scope._answer));

      $scope.addAnswer = function(todo) {
        var data = {
          answer: $scope.__answer.text,
          comment_pic: $scope.__answer.comment_pic,
        };


        var fd = new FormData();
        for (var key in data) {
          fd.append(key, data[key])
        };

        $http({
          url: '/posturl'
          data: fd,
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': undefined
          }
        }).success(function(data, status) {
          todo.answers.push($scope.__answer);
          $scope._answer.comment_pic = "";
          $scope.__answer = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify($scope._answer));
        });
      };
    });
```

```html
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <form name="addAnswerForm">
    <input ng-model="__answer.text" />
    <input type="file" file-model="__answer.comment_pic" />
    <button type="submit" ng-click="addAnswer(discussion)">Post</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

how to make the form clear after submitting the form
This the file in the input type="file" is not getting cleared
[image]

Answer (score 0):

By clearing the DOM of the form the form is getting cleared.

document.getElementById("MyformId").reset();

if there is another method do tell